# How to add icons to Tamagui Input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, tamagui

I am using [Tamagui Input](https://tamagui.dev/docs/components/inputs/1.0.0) component and I want to add icons to it.

I am having to use a combination of `<Stacks />` to horizonally align buttons (with icons) with my `Input` component like so:

```
const SearchBar = () => {
  return (
    <XStack alignItems="center">
      <Button 
        size="$4" 
        icon={<Search />} 
        marginRight="$-4" 
        borderTopLeftRadius="$4" 
        borderBottomLeftRadius='$4'
        borderTopRightRadius="$0" 
        borderBottomRightRadius="$0" 
        borderColor="$gray12Light"
        backgroundColor='$gray5Light'
        borderWidth="$0"
        borderRightWidth="$0"
      />
      <Input 
        placeholder='Searchword'
        flex={1} 
        borderColor="$gray12Light"
        focusStyle={{
          borderColor: '$gray12Light'
        }}
        borderWidth="$0"
        value={value}
        backgroundColor='$gray5Light'
        borderBottomLeftRadius='$4'
      />
      <Button 
        size="$4" 
        icon={<X/>} 
        display={value?.length ? 'flex' : 'none'}
        onPress={() => handleClear()} 
        marginLeft="$-4" 
        borderTopRightRadius="$4" 
        borderBottomRightRadius='$4'
        borderTopLeftRadius="$0" 
        borderBottomLeftRadius="$0" 
        borderColor="$gray12Light"
        backgroundColor='$gray5Light'
        borderWidth="$0"
        borderLeftWidth="$0"
      />
    </XStack>
  )
}
```

You'll notice I am wrapping my `<Search />` icon and `<X />` icon in a `Button` component. It seems to be the only way to align the icons and be able to set the background color.

This creates an input with a left aligned icon and a right aligned icon like so:

[image]

Does Tamagui provide any props that I can pass icons into my Inputs? Maybe other people have a better solution that what I have? Open to suggestions on how's best to handle this as my current implementation seems very convoluted.

I tried using a `<Stack/>` but it wouldn't allow me to override the colors. But I feel like it's still the same issue that it's a convoluted layout for handling icons on an input.

This is the code using `Stack` instead of `Button`:

```
<XStack alignItems="center">
  <Stack
    marginRight="$-4" 
    borderTopLeftRadius="$4" 
    borderBottomLeftRadius='$4'
    borderTopRightRadius="$0" 
    borderBottomRightRadius="$0" 
    borderColor="$gray12Light"
    backgroundColor='$gray5Light'
    borderWidth="$0"
    borderRightWidth="$0"
  >
    <Search />
  </Stack>
  <Input 
    placeholder='Searchword'
    flex={1} 
    borderColor="$gray12Light"
    focusStyle={{
      borderColor: '$gray12Light'
    }}
    borderWidth="$0"
    value={value}
    backgroundColor='$gray5Light'
    borderBottomLeftRadius='$4'
  />
  ...
```

This is what it results in:

[image]